# Parse resource ids via simplexml in Android

Tags: android, android-resources, simple-framework

In my Android application I need to parse xml like this:

```
<items>
    <item title="@string/item1" />
    <item title="@string/item2" />
</items>
```

I'd like to use *simplexml* for parsing.

But I cannot find anything about parsing resources ids in attributes. Is it possible to parse title attribute as int?

Comment: do you need R.string.item1 value? If yes, this will work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042961/how-can-i-get-the-resource-id-of-an-image-if-i-know-its-name

Comment: Yes, now I do something like this. But I want simplexml to read int value for me, but not to resolve id each time for myself.

Comment: Looks like custom Filter implementation may work for you http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in SAXparser's [**startElement()**](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xml/sax/ContentHandler.html#startElement%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.xml.sax.Attributes%29)  you will have a parameter named attributes.

see this **[example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778875/sax-xml-parsing-in-android)**

Comment: I know how to do this via SAX parser and PullParser. Now I'm looking for solution for simplexml

Comment: hmmm, can you just have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001052/android-simple-xml-how-to-declare-a-list-of-elements

Comment: I don't see any relation to my question.

Comment: It seems that the only solution is not to use simplexml :(