# Extract feeds list from an OPML file in java

Tags: java, xml, rss, opml

I want to extract a list of feed information from an OPML file in java. I know I have to use some xml-parse technique, but I have no idea what to use.

I am a java beginner, so could you tell me how to do it and give me an example?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should fairly straight forward. You can take one of hte following two approaches.

1. Use java parsing capabilities and parse it as any XML file. Here is an [example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/) using DOM parse.
2. There are lot of the open source code/libraries for doing this. Here is [one such example](https://github.com/danieloeh/AntennaPod/blob/master/src/de/danoeh/antennapod/opml/OpmlReader.java). This class has a method `public ArrayList<OpmlElement> readDocument(Reader reader)`. You can create a `Reader` object from the OPML file and pass the same to this function. Please note that this library depends on [xml Pull parser libraries](http://www.xmlpull.org/v1/download/). So if you do not want to add another dependency use the first approach.
3. Here is [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778875/sax-xml-parsing-in-android) on this forum itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Santosh! This is just what i want!

Comment: @BinZhu,you are welcome. Please accept the answer by clicking on (✓) symbol.